# how to name data frame columns to column index

Tags: r

It is a very basic question.How can you set the column names of data frame to column index? So if you have 4 columns, column names will be `1 2 3 4`.  The data frame i am using can have up to 100 columns.

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this `names(df) <- 1:ncol(df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not good to name the column names with names that start with numbers.  Suppose, we name it as `seq_along(D)`.  It becomes unnecessarily complicated when we try to extract a column.  For example,

```
names(D) <- seq_along(D)
D$1
#Error: unexpected numeric constant in "D$1"
```

In that case, we may need `backticks` or `""`

```
D$"1"
#[1] 1 2 3
D$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3
```

However, the `[` should work

```
D[["1"]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

I would use

```
names(D) <- paste0("Col", seq_along(D))
D$Col1
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Or

```
D[["Col1"]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
D <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9),d=c(10,11,12))
```

Comment: thanks. How can you add the columns of two different data frames with same column names.for example `D <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9),d=c(10,11,12))  D1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9))`

Comment: @HaagenDaz  Try `nm1 <- intersect(names(D), names(D1));D[nm1]+D1[nm1]`

Comment: it works all great, but i also want to keep column `d` in `D` which is not there in `d1`

Comment: @HaagenDaz  In that case, just assign it `D[nm1] <- D[nm1]+D1[nm1]`

Comment: sorry i didn't explain it well, I meant the resulting `D2` to be `D2 <- data.frame(a=c(2,4,6),b=c(8,10,12),c=c(14,16,18),d=c(10,11,12))`

Comment: @HaagenDaz If you want it as a new dataset, try `D2 <- D; D2[nm1] <- D2[nm1]+D1[nm1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `names`:

```
D <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9),d=c(10,11,12))

names(D) <- 1:ncol(D) # sequence from 1 through the number of columns
```